# Rendering multiple objects in OpenGL when the number of objects is dynamic

Tags: opengl

I am writing a game with OpenGL shaders, which displays a number of objects that are moving around on the screen. The number of objects is dynamic, such that objects sometimes disappear from the game, and sometimes new objects are introduced (e.g. a game where you are trying to kill waves of enemies).

How should I render these objects?

My first thought was to have one VAO per object I am rendering, each with its own VBO. When the object dies, then I remove the VAO and VBO from the game. When a new object is introduced, I create a new VAO and VBO. The problem with this approach is that there could be thousands of such objects, and so it seems rather a lot to have so many VAO's and VBO's.

My second thought was to have one VAO and one VBO, and where the VBO is dynamic. So when an object dies, I remove its vertex data from the VBO. When a new object is introduced, I add vertex data to the VBO. The problem with this approach is that in order for the VBO to have a contiguous set of vertices to be rendered, each time an object dies I would need to copy the entire contents out again whilst removing the dead objects. This seems rather a lot of work.

What is the standard solution?

Answer (score 0):

The "standard solution" is to decide up front what you're actually doing. If you have a "level" in a game, then you typically have a fixed set of meshes that may need to be rendered. You have some level geometry, level decorations, and various characters that you might want to render.

You build a buffer object containing all of that data, and you render what you need from it as you need it. If you have 3 characters who use the same mesh, you render that mesh 3 times, using different uniform data that determines what it looks like (textures, colors, etc) and where it gets rendered (transforms, etc).

You don't delete a mesh's data just because an entity was killed off.

There are scenarios when you actually need to dynamically manage memory. But that's only because the totality of the stuff you want to render *exceeds* the available storage, and/or when your world can't be broken up into discrete levels.